# About a index of blog and show description and show all

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i got a problem about blog making
i need something like the site railcast
which is before enter the title i will see the index page description with limited row
after enter the title only see the full paragraph
i failed to do in this way

```
My index View ::

<% for post in @posts %>
    <div class="blogPost">
        <h2>
            <%= link_to h(post.title), post %>
        </h2>
            <b>Category:</b><%=h post.category.category_name %><br/>
            <b>Posted at:</b><%=h post.date_of_creation %><br/>
            <%= "#{post.comments.count} Comments" %><br/>
        <div class="body">   
            <p><%= post.description %></p>
            <p><%=link_to "Read More...", post %></p>
        </div>
        <div class="action">
            <%= link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(post) %>
            <%= link_to "Destroy", post, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
        </div>
    </div>

My controller ::
def index
    @posts = Post.paginate :per_page => 5, :page => params[:page], :order => 'created_at DESC'   

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.js do
        render :update do |page|
          page.replace_html 'post', :partial => "post"
        end
       end
      format.xml  { render :xml => @posts }
      format.json { render :json => @posts }
      format.atom
    end
  end
```

and

```
New Post Form ::
<h1>New post</h1>

<% form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :body %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :date_of_creation %><br />
    <%= f.date_select :date_of_creation %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="category">Category<br/></label>
    <select name="category">
        <% @cat.each do |category|  %>
        <option value="<%= category.id %>">
        <%= category.category_name  %>
        </option>
        <% end %>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit 'Create' %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

is that i need to create a new column call description or what
i failed to call it up with

```
<div class="body">   
            <p><%= post.description %></p>
            <p><%=link_to "Read More...", post %></p>
        </div>
```

Guy here have any better idea ?
Thx for reply ~

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution which was to use the truncate method.